# Java Arrays.fill()

Tags: java, arrays, fill

How to fill a multidimensional array?

```
int[][] array = new int[4][6]; 
Arrays.fill(array, 0);
```

I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did any of the solutions given work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrays.fill with multidimensional array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118178/arrays-fill-with-multidimensional-array-in-java)

Comment: If the array doesn't need to be a jagged array, you could create a single dimensional array (of size width * height) and just access it via `int index = (y * width) + x;` -- you could even create a class that just exposes get/set methods that take x and y as separate arguments.  Then you could fill the whole array without any looping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 31):

Here's a suggestion using a for-each:

```
for (int[] row : array)
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
```

You can verify that it works by doing

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

---

A side note: Since you're creating the array, right before the fill, the fill is actually not needed (as long as you really want zeros in it). Java initializes all array-elements to their corresponding default values, and for `int` it is 0 :-)

Comment: for instance variables java does(automatic initalization) but not for local variables So above the above code adds importance in some cases

Comment: @JoelDeWitt, why? :)

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Arrays.fill(array[i], 0);
}
```

I haven't tested it but I think it should work.

Comment: This is using fill for a regular int array only, hence the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since array is really an array of arrays, perhaps you can try looping over each row and doing fill for each one individually.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `0` is the default value for int arrays, so you don't have to fill something with 0.

If you want your array to stay truly multidimensional, you'll need a loop.

```
public static void fill(int[][] array, int element) {
    for(int[] subarray : array) {
        Arrays.fill(subarray, element);
    }
}
```

If you only need a 2D-array filled with the same element and don't want to change the subarrays later, you can use this trick:

```
public static int[][] create2DArray(int length, int subLength, int element) {
    int[] subArray = new int[subLength];
    Arrays.fill(subArray, element);
    int[][] array = new int[length][];
    Arrays.fill(array, subArray);
    return array;
}
```

This works analogously for higher-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score -3):

See this way:

```
Arrays.fill(array[0], 0);
Arrays.fill(array, array[0]);
```

Comment: This makes every sub-array, the exact same array, so that if you change `array[0][0]`, you also change `array[1][0]`, `array[2][0]`, ... to the same value. Not a good solution.