# Java Arrays.fill() negative number

Tags: java, arrays, exception, 2d, fill

I am trying to fill a 2D array with '-1' as all the values. The code that I'm using is:

```
int c [] []=new int[4][4];
Arrays.fill(c,-1)
```

This throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118178/arrays-fill-with-multidimensional-array-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its an array of array of Integer.

You should write

```
    int c [] []=new int[4][4];
    for(int[] arr : c){
        Arrays.fill(arr,-1);
    }
```