# When using Java Arrays.fill(array,int[] subArray), why subArray share the same memory block?

Tags: java, arrays, jvm

```
int[][] dp = new int[5][2];
Arrays.fill(dp,new int[]{2,3});
dp[1][0] = 10;
```

I thought that only dp[1][0] is changed to 10, but all dp[x][0] are 10(x is from 0 to 4).
I have found a comment related to my problem, "This line makes every row refer to the same memory block, i.e. changing arr[1][5] will also change arr[100][5]."
So why these array objects share the same memory? Are they all in the JVM heap or constant pool?

Related link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19199560/13724489

Comment: An `int[][]` is an array of arrays. If you fill it with `new int[2]{2,3}`, then you are putting that one array into your array of arrays multiple times.

Comment: Because arrays are objects, and fill copies the **reference** to the array to each entry of the array `dp`, it doesn't copy the array itself. So each entry in `dp` points to the same array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would think that `Array.fill(dp, new int[2]{2,3})` is equivalent to:

```
dp[0] = new int[2]{2,3};
dp[1] = new int[2]{2,3};
dp[2] = new int[2]{2,3};
dp[3] = new int[2]{2,3};
dp[4] = new int[2]{2,3};
```

But no, it's more like:

```
int[] val = new int[2]{2,3};
dp[0] = val;
dp[1] = val;
dp[2] = val;
dp[3] = val;
dp[4] = val;
```

You are only ever creating *one* array in the line `Array.fill(dp, new int[2]{2,3})`. All subarrays in `dp` refer to that single array that you created. `dp[0]` and `dp[1]` and `dp[whatever]` all refer to the same array.

This is because when you call a method, all the arguments get evaluated, before the method is run, so `new int[2]{2,3}` is evaluated before `fill` is called. `fill` doesn't "run" the expression `new int[2]{2,3}` in a loop and assign it to the array. `fill` doesn't even know what expression you used! Rather, `fill` only knows the value that the expression `new int[2]{2,3}` evaluated to - a reference to one newly created int array object. `fill` then assigns that same object to each index of `dp`.

Comment: While I hope that my answer will be helpful too, you are giving a better explanation of the question as asked, the *why*. +1.

Answer (score 3):

It’s true what they say:

```
    int[][] dp = new int[5][2];
    Arrays.fill(dp, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    dp[1][0] = 10;
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dp));
```

Output:

> [[10, 3], [10, 3], [10, 3], [10, 3], [10, 3]]

In the code you are only instantiating *one* `int[]` (one one-dimentional array of ints). You are doing `new int[] { 2, 3 })` only once. So you have only one inner array. The `fill` method fills a reference to this same array into every slot of the outer array. This is what happens.

**Two other points**

1. As Holger said in the comment, when we are constructing the inner array/s afterward, also constructing them in the declaration is a waste. Leave out the inner dimension to construct only the outer array first:

   ```
       int[][] dp = new int[5][]; // No number in the second set of square brackets
   ```
2. As an aside you’ve got an error in this line of your code:

   ```
       Arrays.fill(dp,new int[2]{2,3});
   ```

   You are not allowed to give *both* an array dimension (length) *and* contents. In my Eclipse I get *Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided*. So leave out the `2` in the square brackets as I am doing above.

**If you wanted five separate inner arrays**, you may use the `setAll` method:

```
    Arrays.setAll(dp, index -> new int[] { 2, 3 });
```

Now the output will be:

> [[2, 3], [10, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]

What happens now is that `setAll` calls `new int[] { 2, 3 }` for every index of the outer array, so five inner arrays are created.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `int[][] dp = new int[5][2];`, you get an outer array of length 5, and 5 inner arrays of length 2. All 5 inner arrays are filled with `0` values.

```
dp →→→┌───┐   ┌───┬───┐
      │ •→│→→→│ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤   └───┴───┘ ┌───┬───┐
      │ •→│→→→→→→→→→→→→→│ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤   ┌───┬───┐ └───┴───┘
      │ •→│→→→│ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤   └───┴───┘ ┌───┬───┐
      │ •→│→→→→→→→→→→→→→│ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤   ┌───┬───┐ └───┴───┘
      │ •→│→→→│ 0 │ 0 │
      └───┘   └───┴───┘
```

When you then run `Arrays.fill(dp,new int[2]{2,3});`, you create a new array of length 2 with values `2` and `3`, then fill all 5 positions of the outer array with a reference to that new array. The 5 previous inner arrays are discarded:

```
dp →→→┌───┐                  ┌───┬───┐
      │ •→│→→→→→↓            │ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤     ↓            └───┴───┘ ┌───┬───┐
      │ •→│→→→↓ ↓                      │ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤   ┌───┬───┐      ┌───┬───┐ └───┴───┘
      │ •→│→→→│ 2 │ 3 │      │ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤   └───┴───┘      └───┴───┘ ┌───┬───┐
      │ •→│→→→↑ ↑                      │ 0 │ 0 │
      ├───┤     ↑            ┌───┬───┐ └───┴───┘
      │ •→│→→→→→↑            │ 0 │ 0 │
      └───┘                  └───┴───┘
```

Which of course means that `dp[1][0]` and `dp[4][0]` both refer to the same array position, i.e. the position holding the `2` value.

Comment: Wow! Did you type these diagrams by hand, or with a generator?

Comment: @Sweeper By hand. Copy/paste of border lines from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode), and of arrows from [here](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html). Found with web searches for [unicode box drawing](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+box+drawing), [unicode arrow](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+arrow), and [unicode bullet](https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+bullet) •.