# Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Consider:

```
int[][] multD = new int[5][];
multD[0] = new int[10];
```

Is this how you create a two-dimensional array with 5 rows and 10 columns?

I saw this code online, but the syntax didn't make sense.

Comment: yea could also define the two dimensional array as having 10 columns in the first statement. int[][] multD = new int[5][10];

Answer (score 875, accepted):

Try the following:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][10];
```

... which is a short hand for something like this:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][];
multi[0] = new int[10];
multi[1] = new int[10];
multi[2] = new int[10];
multi[3] = new int[10];
multi[4] = new int[10];
```

Note that every element will be initialized to the default value for `int`, `0`, so the above are also equivalent to:

```
int[][] multi = new int[][] {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

... or, more succinctly,

```
int[][] multi = {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

Comment: The fun part is you can have different columns in different rows as well. For example:- int[][] multi = new int[5][]; multi[0] = new int[10]; multi[1] = new int[6]; multi[2] = new int[9] is also perfectly valid

Comment: @JavaTec if we want to hardcode the value, with different column, how should we do that ??

Comment: Hi Muneeb, if i understood correctly, you're asking in a multi-dimensional array, with different column size for each row, how to assign the values. Here'z how: int[][] multi = new int[][]{{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4},{1}}; and you can access/print them like:  for(int i=0; i<multi.length; i++){ for(int j=0; j<multi[i].length; j++){ System.out.println("row:" + i + " column:" + j + " value:"+ multi[i][j]); } }

Comment: Do we need to use `new int[][]` in `=new int[][]{...}` variant? Can we just write `={...}`?

Comment: @Nawaz No, Arrays are Object in java and memory is allocated to Objects only by using `new` keyword.

Comment: @Oldrinb   what about `int array[][] = new int[3][];` VS `int array[][] = new int[][3];` ?? which one is legal as I have read both version somewhere.

Comment: Can we also call it 5 columns and 10 rows?

Comment: @roottraveller that’s wrong, you can [just write `int[][] multi = {  { … }, … };`](https://ideone.com/RjxQw7) Being an object does not imply that writing `new` was the only way to create an object. `String s = "123";` also doesn’t require the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Nawaz a bit late but since the previous reply was just wrong, I want to emphasize that you *can* write `… = { … }`. E.g. https://ideone.com/RjxQw7

Answer (score 86):

We can declare a two dimensional array and directly store elements at the time of its declaration as:

```
int marks[][]={{50,60,55,67,70},{62,65,70,70,81},{72,66,77,80,69}};
```

Here *int* represents integer type elements stored into the array and the array name is 'marks'. *int* is the datatype for all the elements represented inside the "{" and "}" braces because an array is a collection of elements having the same data type.

Coming back to our statement written above: each row of elements should be written inside the curly braces. The rows and the elements in each row should be separated by a commas.

Now observe the statement: you can get there are 3 rows and 5 columns, so the JVM creates 3 * 5 = 15 blocks of memory. These blocks can be individually referred ta as:

```
marks[0][0]  marks[0][1]  marks[0][2]  marks[0][3]  marks[0][4]
marks[1][0]  marks[1][1]  marks[1][2]  marks[1][3]  marks[1][4]
marks[2][0]  marks[2][1]  marks[2][2]  marks[2][3]  marks[2][4]
```

NOTE:
If you want to store *n* elements then the array index starts from zero and ends at *n-1*.
Another way of creating a two dimensional array is by declaring the array first and then allotting memory for it by using new operator.

```
int marks[][];           // declare marks array
marks = new int[3][5];   // allocate memory for storing 15 elements
```

By combining the above two we can write:

```
int marks[][] = new int[3][5];
```

Comment: I think this is the most consise way to enter the data.

Answer (score 54):

You can create them just the way others have mentioned. One more point to add: You can even create a skewed two-dimensional array with each row, not necessarily having the same number of collumns, like this:

```
int array[][] = new int[3][];
array[0] = new int[3];
array[1] = new int[2];
array[2] = new int[5];
```

Comment: Well said! This is the most important aspect of having independent initialization.

Comment: @Victor what about `int array[][] = new int[3][];` VS `int array[][] = new int[][3];` ?? which one is legal as I have read both version somewhere.

Answer (score 30):

The most common idiom to create a two-dimensional array with **5** rows and **10** columns is:

```
int[][] multD = new int[5][10];
```

<sub>Alternatively, you could use the following, which is more similar to what you have, though you need to explicitly initialize each row:</sub>

```
int[][] multD = new int[5][];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  multD[i] = new int[10];
}
```

Comment: Also realize that only primitives do not require initialization.  If you declare the array as `Object[][] ary2d = new Object[5][10];` then you still must initialize each element of the 2D array.

Comment: Unless you handle the `null` case safely for any non primitives. Whether or not you should initialize each element is completely dependent on your design. Also, just to clarify - primitives cannot be null and get instantiated to a defined default value if not assigned one by you. E.g. an `int` cannot be null and when you say `int i;` without assigning a value, the default one of `0` is used. [Read about it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: One further clarification, default values are only handed out to class/instance variables. Local variables (inside methods) must be manually initialized before use.

Answer (score 12):

It is also possible to declare it the following way. It's not good design, but it works.

```
int[] twoDimIntArray[] = new int[5][10];
```

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
int[][] multD = new int[5][10];
```

Note that in your code only the first line of the 2D array is initialized to 0.
Line 2 to 5 don't even exist. If you try to print them you'll get `null` for everyone of them.

Comment: *"Line 2 to 5 don't even exist"*. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 8):

In Java, a two-dimensional array can be declared as the same as a one-dimensional array. In a one-dimensional array you can write like

```
  int array[] = new int[5];
```

where int is a data type, array[] is an array declaration, and `new array` is an array with its objects with five indexes.

Like that, you can write a two-dimensional array as the following.

```
  int array[][];
  array = new int[3][4];
```

Here `array` is an int data type. I have firstly declared on a one-dimensional array of that types, then a 3 row and 4 column array is created.

In your code

```
int[][] multD = new int[5][];
multD[0] = new int[10];
```

means that you have created a two-dimensional array, with five rows. In 
the first row there are 10 columns. In Java you can select the column size for every row as you desire.

Answer (score 8):

```
int [][] twoDim = new int [5][5];

int a = (twoDim.length);//5
int b = (twoDim[0].length);//5

for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){ // 1 2 3 4 5
    for(int j = 0; j <b; j++) { // 1 2 3 4 5
        int x = (i+1)*(j+1);
        twoDim[i][j] = x;
        if (x<10) {
            System.out.print(" " + x + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
    }//end of for J
    System.out.println();
}//end of for i
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int rows = 5;
int cols = 10;

int[] multD = new int[rows * cols];

for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
  for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
  {
     int index = r * cols + c;
     multD[index] = index * 2;
  }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This would be useful in a language that doesn't support 2D arrays like C!

Comment: C supports multi-dimensional arrays too.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
int a[][] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};

int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Answer (score 4):

These types of arrays are known as jagged arrays in Java:

```
int[][] multD = new int[3][];
multD[0] = new int[3];
multD[1] = new int[2];
multD[2] = new int[5];
```

In this scenario each row of the array holds the different number of columns. In the above example, the first row will hold three columns, the second row will hold two columns, and the third row holds five columns. You can initialize this array at compile time like below:

```
 int[][] multD = {{2, 4, 1}, {6, 8}, {7, 3, 6, 5, 1}};
```

You can easily iterate all elements in your array:

```
for (int i = 0; i<multD.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<multD[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(multD[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 2):

Actually Java doesn't have multi-dimensional array in mathematical sense. What Java has is just array of arrays, an array where each element is also an array. That is why the absolute requirement to initialize it is the size of the first dimension. If the rest are specified then it will create an array populated with default value.

```
int[][]   ar  = new int[2][];
int[][][] ar  = new int[2][][];
int[][]   ar  = new int[2][2]; // 2x2 array with zeros
```

It also gives us a quirk. The size of the sub-array cannot be changed by adding more elements, but we can do so by assigning a new array of arbitrary size.

```
int[][]   ar  = new int[2][2];
ar[1][3] = 10; // index out of bound
ar[1]    = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // works
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that's dynamic and flexible (i.e. where you can add or remove columns and rows), you could try an "ArrayList of ArrayList":

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayListOfArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayListOfArrayList.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("First", "Second", "Third")));
    arrayListOfArrayList.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth")));
    arrayListOfArrayList.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("Seventh", "Eighth", "Ninth")));
    arrayListOfArrayList.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("Tenth", "Eleventh", "Twelfth")));

    displayArrayOfArray(arrayListOfArrayList);
    addNewColumn(arrayListOfArrayList);
    displayArrayOfArray(arrayListOfArrayList);
    arrayListOfArrayList.remove(2);
    displayArrayOfArray(arrayListOfArrayList);
}

private static void displayArrayOfArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayListOfArrayList) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arrayListOfArrayList.size(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < arrayListOfArrayList.get(row).size(); col++) {
            System.out.printf("%-10s", arrayListOfArrayList.get(row).get(col));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

private static void addNewColumn(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayListOfArrayList) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arrayListOfArrayList.size(); row++) {
        arrayListOfArrayList.get(row).add("added" + row);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First     Second    Third     
Fourth    Fifth     Sixth     
Seventh   Eighth    Ninth     
Tenth     Eleventh  Twelfth   

First     Second    Third     added0    
Fourth    Fifth     Sixth     added1    
Seventh   Eighth    Ninth     added2    
Tenth     Eleventh  Twelfth   added3    

First     Second    Third     added0    
Fourth    Fifth     Sixth     added1    
Tenth     Eleventh  Twelfth   added3
```