# Android beginner - TextView Value Storage in Array

Tags: android

I'm new to stackoverflow so i'm sry if this post is wrong.

Let's say i have this table layout , and each time i click a button it appears a new row (each row has 5 text views).

The thing is i want to store the values of the last textview (textview5) in array , then make a sum of all the values at the end.

But when i do that the array shows only the last value , the previous ones are lost..

Can you guys me show me some example code or a method to do this ? Ty

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you may want to use is a **2D array** rather than a single normal array, since you have multiple rows which keep expending, and multiple columns (your textviews).

With the use of a 2D array, let's say int[][] yourValue = new int[x][y]; You may want to store your textviews in y, and number of the rows in x, that will keep all your data there and avoid one to replace the other each time a new one appears.

For more information about a 2D array please refer to another post I found.

[Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)

Try the following:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][10];
```

... which is a short hand for something like this:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][];
multi[0] = new int[10];
multi[1] = new int[10];
multi[2] = new int[10];
multi[3] = new int[10];
multi[4] = new int[10];
```

Note that every element will be initialized to the default value for int, 0, so the above are also equivalent to:

```
int[][] multi = new int[][]{
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```