# How to store multiple byte arrays

Tags: java, android, arraylist, arrays

I am working on a camera app, I take my picture and the data is gathered as a byte[]...I don't want to store the images on the phones memory, what I want to be able to do is store the byte array for each capture up to a max of 5.  So I'm wondering is it possible to create an array of byte arrays?  Then I can add, remove arrays at the specified index location.  Perhaps an array list?  or do I have to use a db?

I've researched but came up with nothing, any thoughts would be appreciated.

****EDIT****

So just to ensure what I'm doing is correct here is my code..

```
public void addImage(byte[] IMdata) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Traverses Through ImageByteArray
        for (int i = 0; i < ImageByteArray.length; i++) {
            //Checks index position is empty
            if (ImageByteArray[i] == null) {
                //If so store IMdata in the Array
                ImageByteArray[i] = IMdata;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I'm wondering is it possible to create an array of byte arrays?

Yes , its called [two-dimentaional arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arraySetGet.html)(scroll down to *Accessing Elements of a Multidimensional Array*.

```
byte[][] twoDByteArray=new byte[5][1024];
```

Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array).

Comment: You never know how big that array is going to be when the user captures an image. So allocating 5 x 1024 seems useless. Maybe allocating 5 x unset is more better. Something like: `byte[][] twoDByteArray = new byte[5][];`

Comment: @gunar its a sample code. I assume that op understand 1d byte arrays. and how he will use it depends on him.