# Receiving a null pointer exception when trying to use toString

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, getstring

I am trying to access a local database and pull the data out and store it in an array...but I keep receiving a null pointer exception, please help?

```
int rows = 0;
int colNum = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
res.beforeFirst();

while(res.next()){
    rows++;
    for(int i = 1; i < colNum; i++){
        teamTable[rows - 1][colNum - 1] = res.getString("Team");
        teamTable[rows - 1][colNum - 1] = res.getInt("Goal Difference");
        teamTable[rows - 1][colNum - 1] = res.getInt("Points");
        System.out.println(teamTable[rows - 1][colNum - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the stack trace, and indicate the line of your sample code to which the line number in the stack trace refers.

Comment: The error occurs on the first res.getString("Team") line...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TheDatabaseConnecter.main(TheDatabaseConnecter.java:46)

Comment: Please copy-paste your whole .java file (as short as possible) and the whole stack trace.

Comment: What purpose serves the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that you haven't initialized the `teamTable` multidimensional array properly. Does it have enough rows? Have you called `teamTable[rowIndex] = new Object[colNum];`? If you forgot about the second one, or `teamTable` is just null, then you get a NullPointerException.

If this isn't clear, then read a tutorial about Java multidimensional arrays, e.g. the answers for this question: [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)