# I want to convert this C code to java code but im having a issue in inputting in array

Tags: java, c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAXROW 10
#define MAXCOL 10

int main()
{
     int arr2d[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
     int i, j, row, col;
     int sumRow[MAXROW] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
     int sumCol[MAXCOL] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
     int totalRow = 0;
     int totalCol = 0;
     system("cls");    
     puts ("Enter the number of rows: "); 
     scanf ("%d", &row);
     puts ("Enter the number of cols: "); 
     scanf ("%d", &col);
     if ((row <= MAXROW) && (col <= MAXCOL))
     {
        printf("Enter %d values: \n", (row * col));
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &arr2d[i][j]); 
                totalRow += arr2d[i][j];  
            }
            sumRow[i] = totalRow;
            totalRow = 0;
        } 
        // getting the sum of cols
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                 totalCol += arr2d[i][j]; 
            }
            sumCol[j] = totalCol;
            totalCol = 0;
        }
        puts("Matrix: \n");
        // printing
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                printf("\t%d\t", arr2d[i][j]);
            }

            printf("\t=%d", sumRow[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {

            printf("\t=%d\t", sumCol[i]);
        }    
        puts ("\n");
     }
     else
     {
         puts ("row and / or col has exceeded the maximum value.");    
     }

     system("pause"); 
 }

==================================================================
THIS IS MY CODE IN JAVA

import java.io.*; 
public class arr2d 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int maxr = 10, maxc = 10;
        int[][] arr2d = new int[maxr][maxc];
        int x,y,row,col,trow= 0,tcol = 0;
        int[] sumCol = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int[] sumRow = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: "); row = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print("Enter the number of cols: "); col = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        //process
        if( (row <= maxr) && (col <= maxc))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter "+ row*col+ " values");
            for(x=0; x<row; x++)// i think i have the problem here
            {
                for(y=0; y<col; y++)
                {
                    arr2d[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                    trow += arr2d[x][y];
                }
                sumRow[x] = trow;
                trow = 0;

            }
            for(y=0; y<col; y++)
            {
                for(x=0; x<row; x++)
                {
                    tcol += arr2d[x][y];

                }
                sumCol[y] = tcol;
            }
```

i think i have a problem on the process i can only enter 2 integers in the 2d array i cant fill all the slot in the array this is what compiler says

```
Enter the number of rows: 2 
Enter the number of cols: 2 
Enter 4 values 
1 
2 after i enter the 2nd value this what happens
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "" at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504) at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) at
>   arr2d.main(arr2d.java:31)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Two-Dimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: Do you know what a `NumberFormatException` is? It might help to look  it up.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` the message is pretty clear: you're trying to convert an empty string to a number, which can't succeed. Either check whether the string is empty, catch the exception and handle accordingly, or check your code why the string is empty (if it is not user-entered).

Comment: Its because the input string you got from br.readLine() was empty i.e. "". This must have happened when you just press 'enter' key without entering number. Instead add a check to see if the value entered is something, and not null. You will have to handle situations also to check if the input is a number and not some text.. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `Scanner` class instead of `BufferedReader` as sometime when you enter `empty` string by mistake then you get `NumberFormatException`from `Integer.parseInt`.
Example,

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter input :");
int text= s.nextInt();
```

`Scanner` class has inbuilt function which can wait until some desired primitive type value is entered.
**Note** the inbuilt functions like `nextInt`, `nextByte` etc  may throw `InputMismatchException` if you are entering non-numeric values when a numeric value is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You got a NumberFormatException because you typed an empty string "" instead of an Integer and this empty String cannot be parsed.

Your program runs fine. I only get the exception when I press Enter without putting any input (in other words passing as input an empty string).

Comment: thanks for the info sir i should study the NumberFormatException

Comment: @Trick You're welcome! If you believe my answer helped you a bit you should upvote it. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong I just ran it through and everything worked. I used your exact test data as well. I'm assuming you just put in wrong data.