# Creating an array of Chars and objects?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array that contains several different things, so that I can display a sort of maze in the command line. I am trying to use `'*'` as the walls, and `' '` as empty spaces, but I would also like to add references to different objects, such as piles of gold, and little traps that are represented by characters like 'g' for gold, and 't' for trap.

All of the objects in the maze are going to be subclasses of a MazeObject class. So my question is whether I make the array out of chars, and how would I put object instances into the array, or should I make it a MazeObject array, but how do I include the `'*'` as walls, and `' '` as spaces. Or is there some way to have a MazeObject array of chars?

```
MazeObject maze[][] = new MazeObject[rows][columns]
```

or

```
char maze[][] = new char[rows][columns]
```

or polymorphism?

```
MazeObject[][] maze = new char[rows][columns]
```

Comment: I would say make an array of MazeObjects with each one having a "physical representation" as a char member.

Comment: @Leifingson how would I go about adding the '*' and ' '? should I create separate objects for those?

Comment: @bob Do you really need a two dimensional array?

Comment: @FunctionR I am trying to create a 2d game board. I am not sure how else to do this?

Comment: @bob I would assign coordinates to each object using a Vector2d, which gives you **x** and **y** for each object. Check my answer.

Comment: @FunctionR This seems like a much better answer, but unfortunately my teacher is asking us to implement this file explicitly using 2d arrays. My main problem was that he never described which kind.

Comment: @bob Ok I added exactly what you need to my answer. Now you have all the tools needed to fill a 2-D array. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the MazeObject like the code below. Notice that `char representation` is really just a name or a character representation of your object. Then `Object actualObj` will be the physical object that you want in the maze.

```
public class MazeObject
{
    private char representation;
    private Object actualObj;

    public MazeObject(char r)
    {
        representation = r;
    } 

    public char getRepresentation()
    {
        return representation;
    }
}
```

Then you can make a list out of those by doing this:

```
int row = 5;
int col = 5;
MazeObject [][] list = new MazeObject [row] [col];
```

---

**How do you populate a two dimensional array?**

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array), but still that answer is for ints. You are using `MazeObjects` so keep that in mind.

### Solution

```
    MazeObject [][] list = new MazeObject [5] [5];

    list[0][0] = new MazeObject('a');

    System.out.println(list[0][0].getRepresentation());
```

Good luck with the rest, now you have all the tools needed to fill your 2-D array.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind in my previous comment, thank you for elaborating.