# How to insert a string into a 2D string array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm new to Java.

```
String[][] data = new String[][];
data[0][0] = "Hello";
```

This does not work, so can anyone explain why and how to make it work?
Well, in C++/Cli this works perfectly but not in Java.

It says:

> cannot find symbol: class data

Comment: size of array is required...

Comment: Even with String[][] data=new String [5][5]; Does not work

Comment: Please post the whole error message. Also post more of the code so we get context about its location.

Comment: what do ya mean `Does not work`?

Comment: Ok , I got it, it does not work when it is put inside a class, but why?

Comment: Because the body of a class is for declarations, not executable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the number of rows and columns of the array while declaring it:

```
String[][] data = new String[2][3];
```

This will initialize an array with 2 rows and 3 columns. In general:

```
String[][] data = new String[rows][columns];
```

You can also ommit the number of columns:

```
String[][] data = new String[2][];
```

but to be able to fill it, you will have to initialize each row separately:

```
String[][] data = new String[2][];
data[0] = new String[3];
data[1] = new String[3];
```

Comment: They aren't columns? What would be a more appropriate name?

Comment: String[][] data=new String [5][5]; , even if I add it, it does not work.

Comment: @Christian may be "depth" or "size" ?

Answer (score 0):

While declaring Array, You need to give dimensions.

For example...

```
String[][] data=new String [rows][cloumns];
```

where rows and columns are integers.

for One dimension array

```
String[] data = new String[size];
```

PS.

This question may be helpful : [Creating Two-Dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12231453/1686291)

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly after specifying dimensions for array:

```
String[][] data=new String [10][10];
data[0][0]="Hello";
```