# How can I add a String to a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a project I am working in in my comp sci class and I completely forgot how to add a String to a 2-dimensional array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751603/how-to-insert-values-in-two-dimensional-array-programmatically

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really a place to get solutions to homework questions. You need to come up with some code and ask for help on specific problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051554/in-java-how-do-you-insert-a-string-into-a-2d-array-of-string

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score -1):

You can do this like below:

> String[][] array = new String[2][2];      // Initializing 2x2 array that will contains Strings
>
> array[0][0] = "Some text"; // Put String object into array at index 0-0
>
> System.out.println(array[0][0]); // Print element from array at index 0-0

Answer (score -2):

Reading strings and store them to 2 dimensional array :

```
   String[][] data=new String [10][10];
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
          data[i][j]=sc.nextLine();
      }
    }
```

This will dynamically input the strings and store in 2D array.

Answer (score -3):

The answer depends on which programming language you're using. Generally speaking, you'll access the `2D` array through its rows and columns with indices. Then, to add an element to that location in the array, you'll simply assign a string to that particular location. For example, in `Java` you'll do the following:

```java
    String[][] arr = new String[10][10];
    arr[0][0] = "Element 0";
```