# Getting values from multiple arrayLists in java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, arraylist

i've just recently started with java on my school, and i have a bit of a problem.  Well not really a problem, since i've found a way to solve it (complicated one though).

im supposed to make a poemgenerator.

so, in a for loop, i want to build a string, of words that is in some arrayLists, so im using a StringBuilder for that.

the thing is, that my sentence should consists of words from 4 different arrayLists, (different wordclasses)

and, a while ago, i programmed in actionscript3, and there was something there that i could really use for this problem, that would make the code so much simplier.  using This[]

so. i have 4 lists: list0, list1, list2, list3

and in my loop, i would've done something like the following in AS3(flash, actionscript3)

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    poem.append(This["list" + i].get(randomindex))
}
```

so that the first time the loop goes, i get a random word from list0,  the second time, i get a random word from list1, and so on...
is there any way to do this simple in java? x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array;

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("String1", "String2");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("String3", "String4");
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("String5", "String6");
List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("String7", "String8");
List<String>[] lists = new List[]{ list1, list2, list3, list4};
```

Then replace your code with

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    poem.append(lists[i].get(randomindex));
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to make this work,  but im sure im doing something wrong...   as i said, im quite new to java x)

should i change my wordlists : list0, list1  and so on to arrays instead? or can i keep them as ArrayLists?

Comment: as far as i understood, i need to do this :

         List<String>[] lists = new List<String>[]{list0, list1, list2, list3};

but then i get the error :  Cannot create a generic array of List<String>

Comment: `List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList();

List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList();

List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList();

List<String> list4 = Arrays.asList();

List<String>[] lists = new List<String>[]{list1, list2, list3, list4};`

i still get same error

Comment: I get it. it is impossible create generic array. Fixed.

Comment: i Fixed it! but you clearly helped me alon the way! :) thx :P

just the names of them are made so they fit in my program in my language x)

`ArrayList<String> ordListe = new ArrayList<String>();

 ArrayList<String> adjektivListe = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> artikkelListe = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> substantivListe = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> verbListe = new ArrayList<String>();
 List[] lists = new List[]{verbListe, artikkelListe, adjektivListe, substantivListe, verbListe};`

Answer (score 1):

Make a `fullList : List<List<String>>` contains your `list0-3`

```
Random r = new Random();
StringBuildr poem = new StringBuilder();
for (List<String> list : fullList)
    poem.append(list.get(r.nextInt(list.size())));

poem.toString(); //this is your poem
```

codes are not written in IDE, not tested either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two dimensional array [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)

```
list[0] = {"firstWordA","firstWordB"};
list[1] = {"secondWordA","secondWordB"};
list[2] = {"thirdWordA","thirdWordB"};
list[3] = {"fourthWordA","fourthWordB"};

for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    poem.append(list[i][randomindex])
}
```

Comment: This would work, but Talex's solution works better with the OP's question, due to combining List's, rather than arrays.

Comment: oh yeah, did not see that.