# Array 2D looping

Tags: java

I have a problem to understand array 2D looping concept. This is my code :

```
int[][] matA = new int[2][3];
matA[0][0] = 2;
matA[0][2] = 3;
matA[1][1] = -4;

for (int i = 0; i < matA.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < matA[0].length; j++){
        System.out.print("\t" + matA[i][j]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```

I know that `matA[0].length` used for displaying what is second array or `[3]` contain, I just don't understand how `[0]`  on `metA[0].length` can displaying the second array

Comment: You need: `j < matA[i];`

Comment: It works because `matA[0]` and `matA[1]` are the same length in your example (3). So `j` is 0, 1 and then 2 (when j is 3 the loop stops).

Comment: this thread might help you understand 2d array better

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it

```
int[][] matA = new int[2][3];
matA[0][0] = 2;
matA[0][2] = 3;
matA[1][1] = -4;

for (int i = 0; i < matA.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < matA[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print("\t" + matA[i][j]);
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```