# How to call a jagged array method?

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

Im trying to call a jagged array method but Im missing the right syntax
this is my method

```
public static int[] CountAvrge(int[][] a)
{
}
```

now I want to call my CountAvrge method from the static void Main(string[] args)

something like this:

```
CountAvrge(new int[][] { 1, 2, 3 } {4, 5, 6});
```

Comment: This isn't a jagged array, this is a 2D array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Two-Dimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[][] array = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

For the sake of completeness...

```
[Test]
        public void ShouldDoAnArray()
        {
            int[][] _array = new int[][] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 } };
            DoSomething(_array);

        }

        public void DoSomething(int[][] array)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(2, array.Length);
            int[] firstArray = array[0];
            Assert.AreEqual(3, firstArray.Length);
            int[] secondArray = array[1];
            Assert.AreEqual(3, secondArray.Length);
        }
```

Comment: Waitaminute.  This ain't no C# (although there's very little syntactic difference between the two.)

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed. Swore it was a C# tag before, because that's where I usually stroll.