# Using 2-dimensional arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

Using a 50 by 70, 2-Dimensional array, write a java program that draws the figure below.?(Just make use of the given length given) but i must look something like this below:

```
                             *      *
                           ****    ****
                          ******  ******
                 ************************
                  ******  ******      
                   ****    ****
                     *       *
```

I tried my code, but i am not that familiar with 2-D arrays in java

import java.util.*;
    public class triangle
    {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
      int height = 70;
       int x = 1, y = 70;

```
    int j;

  char triangularArray[][] = new char[50][70];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(j=-i; j<=i; j++){
          triangularArray[x+i][y+j]='*';
        }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<triangularArray.length; i++) {
        for( j=0; j<triangularArray.length; j++) {
           System.out.println(triangularArray[i][j]==0 ? ' ' : '*');
        }
       System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [2d arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12231474/4279440)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Using a 50 by 70, 2-Dimensional array, write a java program that draws the figure below

Comment: So, you are asking us to do your homework...

Comment: N-dimensional array is an simple (single dimension) array of (N-1)dimensional arrays

Comment: No, i am asking for help. I tried to do it my way and i have uploaded my code for one triangle but it gives a lot of errors.. And i would appreciate it if someone helped me even with the logic

Comment: What are the errors you get? put up the stack traces and then maybe we can help.

Comment: the error is:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 70
 at triangle.main(triangle.java:15)
"

Comment: Load up full code, integrate the Stacktrace and write down your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without mathematics you can solve it as below :)) your choice...

```
// 1 4 6 8
String[] triangle = new String[]{"    *  ", "  ****  ", " ****** ", "********"};

for (int i = 0; i < triangle.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(triangle[i]);
    System.out.print(triangle[i]);
    System.out.println();
}

for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    System.out.print(triangle[i]);
    System.out.print(triangle[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
```