# Refer To Arrays Dynamically Java

Tags: java, arrays, refer

I have a series of arrays in my Java program

```
Integer[] row1 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
Integer[] row2 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
Integer[] row3 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
Integer[] row4 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
Integer[] row5 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
Integer[] row6 = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

I also have a randomly generated number between 1-6:

```
    int selectrow = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
```

I need to refer to each of those rows based on the value of the generated number. So something like "row" + selectrow and then do something to it, but I am not sure how to achieve this without if statements. If statements would just get too messy. Any ideas?

Comment: You could but you really really shouldn't. Build an array of arrays, or another structure, don't try to access variables by name.

Comment: @DenysSéguret how we could access variable with their names in run time? using reflection?

Comment: Alright Denys, I trust you, I'll just make the array of arrays :)

Comment: Good. Please use also loops to fill your matrix ;) And use int, not Integer, if you have no reason to use objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array of arrays.

And use `int`, not `Integer`, unless you have a very specific reason for using expensive objects.

And use loops to fill your matrix. Unless you fill it with `0` and use `int`, because, well, it's the default value.

All in one, here's what your code could be like:

```
    int[][] matrix = new int[6][6];
    Random rand = new Random();
    // there's probably something happening here
    int[] selectedRow = matrix[rand.nextInt(6)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with an array of arrays:

```
Integer[][] rows = createRows();
int selectrow = rand.nextInt(6);
Integer[] = rows[selectrow];
```

Note that I removed the `+1` part in the initialization of variable `selectrow`. Arrays in Java have 0-based indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using separate variables for each row, you're almost always better off using a [two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array) instead. Selecting a new row is trivial then:

```
Integer[] row = rows[rand.nextInt(6)];
```

(Note that indices start at 0, not 1.)

Answer (score 0):

Add them to an array of arrays:

```
Integer[][] arrays = { row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6 };
Integer[] row = arrays[selectRow];
```