# Getting the longest sequence in 2D Integer array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've been stuck in this problem for a while. The goal is to return an Arraylist of the longest repetitive sequence. If I have

```
int[][] a = {{ 1, 1, 3, 4 }
             { 2, 2, 2, 1}
             { 3, 3, 3, 3}
             { 0, 0, 1, 1}};
```

The method `longestSequence()` should return an Arraylist of `[3,3,3,3]` as `3` has the longest sequence. I have to find sequence only horizontally. Please could smb tell me what I did wrong?

```
   int[][] a = {{ 1, 1, 3, 4 }
                 { 2, 2, 2, 1}
                 { 3, 3, 3, 3}
                 { 0, 0, 1, 1}};

    public List<Integer> longestSequence(int[][]a){
       int count = 1, max = 1;
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          for(int j = 1; j < a[i].length; j++) {
             if (a[i][j] >= a[i][j-1]) {
                count++;
                list.add(a[i][j]);
             }  else {
                   if (count > max) {
                   max = count;
               }
            list.clear();
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: your 2d array is wrong .commas required between elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: @KumarSaurabh, the method needs to return the longest sequence, not constuct a 2d array

Comment: You're clearing the list after each iteration. You check if the item is `>=` but you need only `=`.

Comment: Can you tell us what it does, and explain why that is wrong?

Comment: but u did not implenmeted the two array

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks to be that you are not correctly clearing the list, and you aren't keeping the best list as the value to return.

You could keep a `maxList`, the list of elements corresponding to the run of length `max`:

```
max = count; maxList = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Don't simply use `maxList = list`, since that would be cleared by the `list.clear()` call.

Alternatively, keep the value of the element in the longest run (e.g. 3), and then construct a list at the end of length `max` where all elements are e.g. 3.

```
int bestValue = -1;
int bestLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  int[] row = a[i];
  int j = 0;
  while (j < row.length) {
    int start = j++;
    while (j < row.length && row[j] == row[start]) j++;
    if (j-start > bestLength) {
      bestLength = j - start;
      bestValue = row[start];
    }
  }
}
return Collections.nCopies(bestLength, bestValue);
```

Comment: So I need two lists? One for max and one temporary list? @AndyTurner

Comment: For your current approach, you need two lists. I've updated the answer with code that avoids creating any lists during the search.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your implementation. So apart from the 2d dimensional array creation, you keep overriding your result list even if the current seqence is not the maximum one. So to fix this keep a local arrayList to hold the current sequence and only assign it to your result if it's greater than the max.

```
    int[][] a = {{ 1, 1, 3, 4 },
         { 2, 2, 2, 1},
         { 3, 3, 3, 3},
         { 0, 0, 1, 1}};

    public List<Integer> longestSequence(int[][]a){
       int count = 1, max = 1;
       List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       List<Integer> current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          for(int j = 1; j < a[i].length; j++) {
             if (a[i][j] >= a[i][j-1]) {
                count++;
                current.add(a[i][j]);
             }  else{
                  if (count > max) {
                  max = count;
                  result = current;
                  }
                 current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 count = 1;
             }
           }
        }
      return result ; 
    }
```

Comment: It's returning an empty List, @Amr

Comment: @John I fixed it now check it again :)