# Local variable in a method

Tags: java, variables, methods, range

```
public static int[][] toRGB(float[][] gray) {
    int [][]imageRGB;
    for(int i=0; i<gray.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0; j< gray[0].length; j++) {
            imageRGB[i][j]=getRGB(gray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return imageRGB;
}
```

This method won't work. Java tells me that it's because the variable imageRGB hasn't been initialised. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you just defined an handle that point to null and it is not initialized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: You should know the length since you have the `gray` array as parameter (which has a length).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike member variables, local variables are not initialized by default in Java. In Java member variables (Objects) are initialized to `null` by default. Thus compiler will not complain but your code will throw `NullPointerException` at runtime. To avoid Exception, you must create instance of it (using `new`) before using it.

In your case, you need to create a new instance of the array before using it. Try this:

```
int [][]imageRGB = new int[length][length];
```

If you are not sure about the length of the imageRGB, try using List or Set Collection in Java.

```
List<List<Integer>> = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I can raise many questions about your first paragraph, could you make it better so I can vote you up? Just one point, array is object cuz it used new keyword and it is not even member variables ? I do not understand what do you mean by Java member variables ?