# Use indexOf for 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, indexof

Hello I create a 2D array and i want to find the position from the first 2 in the array. And after to add the index in a new ArrayList. But this code doesn't work. Any idea for the problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> tableau = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[][] tab = {
                        {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                    };

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            int j = tab[i].indexOf(2);
            for (int k = j ; k < tab[i].length; k++) {
                if (tab[i][j] == 2){
                    tableau.add(j);
                }
            }

        }
        for (Integer row : tableau) {
                System.out.println("row = "+ Arrays.toString(tableau));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working, do you have an error message you can include?

Comment: ??? Is not a array tab? This is the method shows at my school for create an 2D array

Comment: @Lima Yes I have 
Test.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
   int j = tab[i].indexOf(2);
                 ^
  symbol:   method indexOf(int)
  location: class int[]. The ^ is under the dot

Comment: then your school has bad Java teachers :)

Comment: In this topic there are the same methote ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/18052343/3741098

Comment: where do you see an indexOf method?

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish? Even if the code executed, it would not accomplish what you are trying to do. You don't even use the `k` index in your inner for loop. And you are printing the entire ArrayList for each item in your ArrayList. If this code was even able to execute it would print something like `row = 0, 0, 0, 0, 1`, but it would print it 5 times. It is very unclear what you are even attempting to do with the program in general, even after your syntax errors are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, regular arrays do not have an `indexOf` method, meaning that you will get an error when you compile.

However, you can easily create your own method to use as a substitute.

```
private static int indexOf(int value, int[] array)
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == value)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then you can just replace this line:

```
int j = tab[i].indexOf(2);
```

With this one:

```
int j = indexOf(2, tab[i]);
```