# Building ArrayList - Complex

Tags: java, arraylist

I am wanting to building an `ArrayList`, that later will be used to display information to a table.

The Issue is, I want my array to contain information that is in increments of 5000, up to 150+% the initial value.

IE:

User enters 100000.

The information in the array would look as such.

```
100002
105002
110002
115002
120002
125002
.
.
.
.
150002
155002
```

No code yet other than collect user input, just looking for a place to start with this.

Comment: Is the table going to have multiple columns? If so, a 2D array may be useful.

Comment: well thats a simple `while/for` loop. and the arraylist i'm assuming would simply just be `ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: Isn't it cheating without a code to show us?

Comment: Yes, Arman it will have two columns.  3kings, I am give the while/for loop a go since that is about the only thing that has made since this far.

Comment: Please show an example of a table (what you want it to output).

Comment: if a user inputs 100002 the +50% (150%) would be 150003. **Its not a factor of 5000!!!! and 50% will not be reached by 5000-step, its at least 49.99871% **

Comment: Peter, I got that, it doesn't have to end with the figured value from the user input.

Comment: @MatthewKelsay So is my solution what you needed? Or do I need to edit it

Comment: But it could and that makes the question questionable. There is a clash between the relative-absolute 5000 and the relative-relative 50%. Remove the 50% and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @PeterRader that better?

Comment: @MatthewKelsay My solution satisfies this.

Comment: @Arman as Peter pointed out this solution would be the result of 49.99871%. I would need the last value to end on 155002 not 150002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double num = sales * 1.5 + 5000;
ArrayList<Double> salesArList = new ArrayList<Double>();
double i = sales;
do{
    salesArList.add(i);
    i = i + 5000;
}while(i <= num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input = 100000;//user input
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i <= (input/2); i+=5000){
     nums.add(input+i);
 }
```

This loop will get you started, if you'd like to have multiple columns, then you can use a 2D array instead. If you have further questions about 2D arrays, I would look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array).

Comment: If I input 100002 result will not be +50%

Comment: Why do `double` math? `max / 2` would suffice. Why the extra parenthesis in `add((max+i))`? Just do `add(max+i)`. And the input isn't really "max", but rather "input", "start", or "min" if anything.