# 2D array in java and using it as 1D

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was going through some basic MCQ questions in Java and I was unable to understand this one.

```
 public class CommandArgsThree {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String[][] argCopy = new String[2][2];
         int x;
         argCopy[0] = args;
         x = argCopy[0].length;
         for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
             System.out.print(" " + argCopy[0][y]);
         }
     }
 }
```

and the command-line invocation is

> java CommandArgsThree 1 2 3

Now what I can't understand is that the `argCopy` has been declared as a 2D array then how can it be used as 1D couple of lines later where `argCopy[0]` has been assigned the value of args?

P.S: I also know that argCopy[0] is 1D array that's why I am asking how can we use the 2D array as 1D here?Means is it legal to do so?

Comment: I think it could be helpful for you:
[Syntax for creating a two dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argCopy` is a 2D array aka an array of arrays. Therefore, the elements `argCopy[0]` and `argCopy[1]` will hold 1D arrays of default size 2. And since `args` is a 1D array, argCopy[0] can be reassigned from an empty array of size 2 to the array known as `args`. To access the individual elements of each 1D array within the 2D array, you not only have to identify the index of the array but also the index of the element. For example, `argCopy[0][0]` will let you access the first element of the first array. If the concept of `argCopy[0].length` confuses you, all it means is the number of elements of the first array. In your case, it started out as 2, but once you reassigned `argCopy[0]` to args, it changed to the length of `args`.

Answer (score 3):

A 2D array is an array of arrays. So argCopy[0] is the array at index 0 which is a 1D array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `argCopy` is 2D but `argCopy[0]` which is assigned to is 1D.

Answer (score 1):

args is assigned as the first element of argCopy at position 0. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this because a 2d array is an array of arrays. Thus when you do something like argCopy[0] you essentially asking the first array how many arrays does you hold?

See this Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), part *Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array*

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class CommandArgsThree 
{
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    String [][] argCopy = new String[2][2]; //Declaration and initialization of argCopy which is a 2D array.
    int x; //Declaration of an integer x
    argCopy[0] = args; // In the first index in the 2D array put the 1D String array args
    x = argCopy[0].length; //Put the length of the array in the 1st index of the 2D array argCopy into x
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) // For loop that runs from 0 till it reaches the value of x
    {
        System.out.print(" " + argCopy[0][y]); // Show in the console what is in the array at index y in the 1st index of the 2D array argCopy
    }
}
}
```

Commented