# Implementing a matrix structure in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, data-structures

What would be the easiest way to implement a matrix of 'set' size m * n in Java? The matrix structure wouldn't need to handle any complex matrix operations such as matrix multiplications or anything, just to hold data - the only thing I would use it for is to access the data at M(i, j), change the data at M(i, j) and set the data at M(i, j) for values 0 <= i < m, 0 <= j < n.

Would the most straight forward approach to this problem be to fill an m-size array with n-size arrays or what is the recommended approach to this? Or is there some better data structure for this altogether?

Comment: 2-dimensional array not good enough?

Comment: if you know the bounds of your data structure, just use a 2D array

Comment: 2-dimensional array sounds fine, how do I make one?

Comment: Search for it in google

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a 2-dimensional array with a size of 5*10:

```
int[][] multi = new int[5][10];
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in a performant way that covers all edge-cases will be difficult if you do not already know how to make a basic implementation.

I would suggest using an existing library for this.

For example, [take a look at toxiclibs](https://github.com/postspectacular/toxiclibs/blob/6896bc17e85320e886bdf0819c66491ce484728e/src.core/toxi/geom/GMatrix.java).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a 2D Array or a library.

For more info you can check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for matrix calculations on complex numbers (math) you may find a library [here](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~squire/download/ComplexMatrix.java).