# Setting a specific element in a 2d array to a random value

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking to set a random value to a certain element in a 2d array.
In my assignment I have to assign a random number 1-5 for the first element in the 2d array and then go the the next row and do the same thing. This is what I have so far but it does not look right.

```
double CURRENT_BOARD [5][5] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
  public double shuffleBoard (double currentBoard) {
  Random rand = new Random();
  shuffledBoard [][] = new double [5][5];
  for (i=0 ;i<5 ;i++) {
    j = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
    shuffledBoard = shuffledBoard [j][0];
  }
  return shuffleBoard;
 }//shuffleBoard
```

My end goal is that the elements of the array will look something like 
{5, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{3, 0, 0, 0, 0}
{4, 0, 0, 0, 0} and so on as long as the first element of the array is selected at random. Can anyone offer any help to make this happen?

Comment: _"it does not look right"_ -- Did you try running it to see what happens?

Comment: return type shuffleBaord() is int but you are returning a 2D int array? there should be compilation error also because of 'huffledBoard = shuffledBoard [j] [0];'.

Comment: Very new to this. I have edited the code a bit but still am looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of a 2D `double` array is not correct.
Take a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)

Declaration should be like

```
double[][] CURRENT_BOARD = new double[][]{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

For random number part, you can try this

```
public double[][] shuffleBoard(double[][] currentBoard) {
    double[][] shuffledBoard = currentBoard;
    Random rand = new Random();
    double rangeMin = 1, rangeMax = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        double j = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * rand.nextDouble();
        shuffledBoard[i][0] = j;
    }
    return shuffledBoard;
}
```

Comment: Getting closer. Wen I run the code now I am getting an incompatible types error. If you could take a look at this it would be great. https://ideone.com/v0Ri9a

Comment: at line 20. `public static double shuffleBoard (double[][] currentBoard)`
change `double` to `double[][]`. Should work.

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thanks! Final question though. The elements in the array go to the 15th decimal. How do I make it a whole number? Change it back to the int data type?