# NullPointerException in processing with 2D array of objects

Tags: processing

I am creating a small game in processing and I am trying to print a 2D array of square objects. I have this `NullPointerException` and I cannot seem to find anything like it on the web.

```java
int edge = 10;
public int sizeOfRect = 50;
public int numberOfRects = 10;
Rectangle[][] player = new Rectangle[numberOfRects][numberOfRects];
public int k;
public int l;
public int kcount=0;
public int lcount=0;

void setup(){
    background(200);
    size(565, 565);
}
void draw(){
    for(k=edge; k<width-edge; k+=55){
        for(l=edge; l<height-edge; l+=55){
            player[kcount][lcount].display();
            lcount++;
        }
        lcount=0;
        kcount++;
    }
    kcount=0;
}
```

and the Rectangle Class

```java
class Rectangle{
   int i;
   int j;
Rectangle(){
    i=k;//xcoor
    j=l;//ycoor
}

void display(){
    fill(0);
    rect(i,j,sizeOfRect,sizeOfRect);
    }

}
```

And finally the exception

> Plain.pde:17:0:17:0: NullPointerException Finished. Could not run the
>   sketch (Target VM failed to initialize). For more information, read
>   revisions.txt and Help? Troubleshooting. Could not run the sketch.

Thank you in advance

Comment: May because you must initialize the two-dimensional array in a `for` loop `player`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a 2D array, but you're never filling that array with any objects. In other words, your 2D array is full of `null` values. That's why you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

You need to fill your array with values. Here's an example:

```
player[1][2] = new Rectangle();
```

You probably want to use a nested `for` loop to fill your array.