# Initialising a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

1. In array, we can initialise something like this:

   `int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`
2. But for two dimensional array, why the below is not correct?

   ```
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          int[][] arr = new int[3][];
          arr[0] = new int[]{1,2,3}; //This is the correct way

          arr[0] = {1,2,3};  // ->Why this is not right? 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: are you looking for an answer other than "because of the java language specification" ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, you are correct the second way of creating a 2D array will not work because when the compiler will compile the code because it couldn't decide its type.

Comment: thank you for your answer Asheesh, but when the first line of code execute: `int[][] arr = new int[3][]` does it indicate that all elements within would be all `int` type?

Comment: @Ruizhi arrays in java are reference types, so when you declare 2d array like `new int[3][]` this means that it will contain an array with 3 null references for another int arrays `[null, null, null]`

Comment: yes because when you write    int[ ][ ] arr  this means that you are going to create an Integer array.  and    new int[3][ ] would allocate memory at runtime .

Comment: @Asheesh Sahu I know Arrays are Object in java and memory is allocated to Objects only by using new keyword. but why for 1D array, it is allowed to use short hand like: `int[] arr = {1 , 2 , 3 }`, but not allowed in 2D array ?

Comment: @Arashigor I think you solved my confusion, thank you

Comment: @Arashigor  thank you, I still want to ask: null references to another `int` type, we can use `new` keyword to allocate memory at runtime, but why for 1D array, it is allowed to use short hand like: int[] arr = {1 , 2 , 3 }, and not allowed in 2D array ?

Comment: @Ruizhi The int[] arr is just the reference to the array of integer. If you create an array with 10 integers, it is the same – an array is allocated and a reference is returned. While, Actually, we can only have the one-dimensional array in Java. 2D arrays are basically the just one-dimensional array of one-dimensional array. So to address that other next array we have to tell the compiler about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use this syntactic sugar during variable initialization time.
Meaning that Java Language Specification allows only 
`arr[0] = new int[]{1, 2, 3};` or `int[][] arr = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};`.
Difference is that the first variant is a variable assignment and the second one is variable initialization.

Comment: thanks, but why I can use array int[] arr ={1,2,3};   I can't use it in 2D array initialisation ?

Comment: You can initialize inline 2D array this way `int[][] arr = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};`

Comment: @Ruizhi check updated answer, hope it will bring clarity

Comment: Thank you Arashigor

Answer (score 0):

The space for the second dimension would be allocate only with the code `new int [ ] { 1, 2, 3}`. Before that the compiler doesn't know what the type of the array items and what the dimension is.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when the `int[][] arr = new int[3][];`  execute, does it tell the compiler that all the elements would be `int` type, and it would be 2 dimension