# Winkler's table in Java

Tags: java, math, jaro-winkler

I'm making a chat-bot, which will answer you by nearest value in dataset (treemaps). System is analog of AIML.

I need to make Winkler-table, which will give me array of result numbers. How to do that?

There is an image, which show how this table works:
[image: WINKLER TABLE]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry, changed.

Comment: It looks obvious. On what stage you have problem? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: *How to do that?* is not much of a question. You need to try doing it yourself and come back with what you have tried and explain what was the problem with it.

Comment: I just don't know how to do that, and post ask here to get an solution.

Comment: Since this is quite a trivial question for any java programmer, it's clear that the OP doesn't know any java at all.  I've at least given a few pointers without actually writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 easy steps.

1. Create a 2 dimensional array for the result matrix:
   see question [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array).

   Dimensions will have to match the input and key lengths of course.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length().
2. Loop over the characters of the input string, and the key as a nested loop.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int).  Basically you have 2 indices which give you 2 `char` values.
3. Compare both characters using the `==` operator and store 0 or 1 in the two-dimensional array using the indices.

Comment: Thank you, gonna try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i made that table.
It looks like next:

```
String[] ts = new String[s2.length()];

int[][] table = new int[s1.length()][s2.length()];
char[] s1c = s1.toCharArray();
char[] s2c = s2.toCharArray();

for(int s1cl = 0; s1cl <= s1c.length - 1; s1cl++) {
    for(int s2cl = 0; s2cl <= s2c.length - 1; s2cl++) {
        if(s1c[s1cl] == s2c[s2cl]) {
            table[s1cl][s2cl] = 0;
        } else {
            table[s1cl][s2cl] = 1;
        }
    }
}

for(int ts1 = 0; ts1 <= s1c.length - 1; ts1++) {
    String res = "";
    for(int ts2 = 0; ts2 <= s2c.length - 1; ts2++) {
        res += ts2;
        if(ts2 == s2c.length - 1) {
            ts[ts1] = res;
            res = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks "herman" for your answer!