# nested part of incompatible type

Tags: java

New to programming here and i keep getting the error message, 'incompatible types, int [] cannot be converted to int.

I have a very simple code and now I want to show a example of my error:

```
int[][] num = new int[2][2];
num[0][0]=1;
num[0][1]=2;
num[1][0]=3;
num[1][1]=4;
if (num[num[num[0][0]]].length >1)
    System.out.println("OK");
```

I've written a lot of code and can't change nested part (in if in this example) at all.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Reza. It would help if you could provide detail on the line in question that gives the error. Also, have a look at this question and its answers. Multidimensional arrays in Java are not very straight-forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num[0][0]` = 1

`num[num[0][0]]` = `num[1]` = [3, 4]

This means that

With `num[num[num[0][0]]]` you're trying to do `num[[3,4]]` which doesn't work in Java. Array index must be an int and in this case you're trying to pass an int array int[]